# jQuery's each function and array inside of it

Tags: arrays, jquery

Having trouble with each function... Will try to explain by example...

In my code, there is DIV with id "media-type-container-1", with content that changes "live", in runtime:

```
<div id="media-type-container-1">
    <div><input type="checkbox">Media 11<span id="media-stations-id-11" class="media-stations-id">11</span></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox">Media 12<span id="media-stations-id-12" class="media-stations-id">12</span></div>
</div>
```

If it changes, it can be chnanged to ie:

```
<div id="media-type-container-1">
    <div><input type="checkbox">Media 13<span id="media-stations-id-13" class="media-stations-id">13</span></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox">Media 14<span id="media-stations-id-14" class="media-stations-id">14</span></div>
</div>
```

To get a list of all "media-stations-id" I use following code:

```
$("#add-to-filter-stations").live("click", function() {

    var selectedMediaStations = new Array();
    selectedMediaStations.length = 0;

    $('#media-type-container-1').each(function(){
        $('.media-stations-id').each(function(){
            selectedMediaStations.push($(this).attr('id').replace("media-stations-id-", ""));
        })
    });
}
```

In mentioned example, array selectedMediaStations get elements 11, 12, 13 and 14, instead of only 13 and 14.

What I'm doing wrong, so I cannot "start" with empty array every time with live function?

Comment: `$('#media-type-container-1').each()`? why are you using `each` for one element?

Comment: jason, media-type-container-1 contains several other div's in it. I need to get a list of those elements and to put them into an array.

Comment: @user198003: `each` loops over elements in a set, not their children.  You probably want something like `$('#media-type-container-1 .media-stations-id').each()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try something like

```
var selectedMediaStations = $('.media-stations-id').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id').replace('media-stations-id-','');
});

// [13, 14]
```

Comment: if it's still the same, you aren't sharing everything with us. please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demoing your problem.